# Windows 10 Universal XAML Toast Notifications

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have  Win 10 Universal App which displays toast notifications based on various events within the app.

My problem is that the toast notifications only get displayed when the app is active (it is not minimized to the task bar).

I need the app to display the notifications when I am using any other apps.
My settings below:
[image]

Toast calling code:

```
private void DisplayNotification()
        {
            string toastXmlString = "<toast>"
                               + "<visual version='1'>"
                               + "<binding template='ToastText04'>"
                               + "<text id='1'>Header</text>"
                               + "<text id='2'>Line 1</text>"
                               + "<text id='3'>Line 2</text>"
                               + "</binding>"
                               + "</visual>"
                               + "</toast>";

            Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument toastDOM = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
            toastDOM.LoadXml(toastXmlString);

            // Create a toast, then create a ToastNotifier object to show
            // the toast
            ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastDOM);

            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
        }
```

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: How are you sending your toast notifications? From Azure, a background service etc

Comment: From a windows universal app, the app refreshes the data at set intervals and based on the results I want it to display some toasts.

Comment: How long is the interval you are setting in the background?

Comment: I have a timer and on tick I check what's the value of it, once it reaches 5 mins, 10 mins, whatever the user selects it pulls data from SQL into a grid and displays a toast.

Comment: As the answer below states your are going to have to create a background task for your application. An issue with background tasks is they can only start every 15 minutes . If the interval is shorter than 15 minutes the background task will not fire.If you want the task to fire more frequently you will have to use Azure or some other services that can fire off the toast at a shorter interval. When an app is minimized it is suspended like on the phone so  it can no longer interact with the user, send toasts etc.

Comment: @sd_dracula I am facing the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new BackgroundTask for that. There are many solutions available out there, but here is the short list:

1. Add a new Windows Runtime Component project to the solution.
2. In the manifest in declarations add a new background task and select Push notifications and/or Timer.
3. Set the entry point to be the fully qualified name (namespace.classname)
4. Register your task at app startup

   if (BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Any(task => task.Value.Name == TaskNameConst)) return;

   BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
   builder.Name = TaskNameConst;
   builder.TaskEntryPoint = TaskEntryPointConst;
   builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
   builder.Register();

Comment: As you can see from the Capabilities image above, I am not seeing any Push/Timer options. The app is a Universal Windows one.

Comment: The capabilities list you have shown is for the app itself (shown in the Capabilities tab of the manifest). My instructions state to use the declarations tab to add a new background task. When you add it you will see capabilities for the task itself.